# Alteração no Formato do arquivo json

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, asp.net-web-api

O meu arquivo está vindo neste formato, mais eu gostaria que não aparecesse esta informação #id antes de venda:

```html
{
  "$id": "1", //como não mostra isso?
  "venda": [
    {
      "$id": "2",
      "poule": 73,
      "idusuario": 4,
      "vendedor": "ITAMAR SOUZA",
      "total": 50.00,
      "datajogo": "2016-01-19T00:00:00",
      "terminal": "(11)985590116",
      "empresa": "SANTIAGO - LOJA 01",
      "nsu": 73
    }
  ]
}
```

Código que esta gerando o Json:

```html
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("consulta/ListarUltimoJogosRalizado/{idusuario}")]
        public HttpResponseMessage ListarTodosJogosAtivos(int idusuario)
        {
            try
            {
                var tTabela = new  JogoAplicacao();
                var listar = tTabela.ListarPoId(idusuario);
                return Request.CreateResponse( HttpStatusCode.OK,  new { venda = listar.ToArray() } );
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Queres remover isso no Javascript? podes fazer `delete obj.$id`, mas seria melhor fazer isso no servidor

Answer (score 1):

Adicione o trecho de código abaixo no seu arquivo `WebApiConfig.cs`:

```
var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.None;
```

Answer (score -1):

Existe um método muito usado que é a utilização de ViewModels.

Você criar uma ViewModel para cada retorno customizado de suas actions da API.

Ex:

```
public class VendaViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Poule { get; set; }
    public int IdUsuario { get; set; }
    public string Vendedor { get; set; }
    public decimal Total { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataJogo { get; set; }
    public string Terminal { get; set; }
    public string Empresa { get; set; }
    public int NSU { get; set; }

    public VendaViewModel ToViewModel(Venda venda)
    {
        // Recomendo refatorar com uso de AutoMapper: http://automapper.org/
        return new VendaViewModel 
        {
            Id = venda.id,
            Poule = venda.Poule,
            IdUsuario = venda.IdUsuario,            
            Vendedor = venda.Vendedor,
            Total = venda.Total,
            DataJogo = venda.DataJogo,
            Terminal = venda.Terminal,
            Empresa = venda.Empresa,
            NSU = venda.NSU
        };
    }
}
```

E no sua action:

```
// ...
var listar = tTabela.ListarPoId(idusuario);
return lista.Select(Venda.ToViewModel);
```

Dessa maneira, vc pode customizar o que realmente será entregue para o client. Inclusive vc pode filtrar campos que não são interessante, reduzindo tráfego, e também formatar saída, por exemplo, do Total, usando configurações regionais.